# Faster way for store static data in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I write small game and have static data of entities

example data of one entity (this data never changed when server working)

```
 id:black-dog
 type:feline
 date:2020-04-22
 location:hills
 level:1
```

I have ~5.000 entities, my game is writing in SPA client and REST API node.js server with MySQL database.

store static data faster way is:

1. storing in MySql Database

or

2. storing like a json or js module (array) and load when server is starting to array (when json)

for safety reason server use JWT tokens.

Comment: Im really new here and please tell me what i write bad if you gives me downvotes, sorry for problem.

Comment: Why are you concerned about the performance of loading static data?  No matter where you store it, you should be able to load it once at server startup time and the slight different between loading it from a database and loading it from a JSON file should make no difference to any customer of your web site at all.

Comment: I thinking about working with data loaded in js array and storing in mysqldatabase and loaded when api have request. I can load from mysql to array too when server start, but faster is when request make select to database or working on js arrays?

Comment: If the data never changes while your server is running and you need it more than once and it's not so gigantic that the memory use is a problem, you should just cache it on the server, no matter where it comes from.  Anytime you can avoid a database call on a frequently hit route, that's a boost for performance.

Comment: It's not a fair comparison or a good question to compare loading every route from a database vs. loading from JSON at startup.  That's like comparing apples and oranges.  The question is whether you should load at startup and cache, no matter whether it comes from the database or the JSON file.  It's a separate issue of server configuration whether you want the data in the database or a JSON file which probably isn't about performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few fairly separate decisions to make:

1. Should you load this data upon server startup or load it every time upon demand?
2. Should you cache this data in memory after you've loaded it so you don't have to fetch it again?
3. Should you store it in your database or in a JSON file?

These are all pretty much independent decisions.

If the data is not large (it appears to be small), the data doesn't change while the server is running and you regularly need it during server requests, then it is a natural to load it once and cache it from then one so you don't have to load it again.  That will improve your server performance by some amount.  So, if those conditions are true, then probably the answer is "yes" to both points 1. and 2.

Whether you store it in the database or in a JSON file has more to do with how you want to manage this data when it is time to change it.  That question doesn't really have to do with server performance, but rather maintenance and configuration of the server and what is most convenient for that.